# AIF custom service TransDate field is rendering as date at 12 PM

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I have a bit of a mystery with a Dynamics AX 2012 R2 CU7 custom service.  It's really simple and it basically assigns some data to a contract for a downstream system to use.

```
orderContract.shippingDateRequested(SalesTable.shippingDateRequested);
```

One of the fields is based on the TransDate EDT.  When I look at the data in sql server, it's the date at midnight which is pretty standard.

My mystery is that when the data comes through the port ( c# console app and BizTalk 2013 R2 as consumers ), the date now comes through as date @ 12 PM.

Am I missing something here or is this by design?  Can I stop this behaviour and have it pass the time as 00:00:00 instead?

Comment: Could it be that you apply a timezone to the field?

Comment: Timezone would be -7 right now. I thought that may have been the case as well, but no go.  Plus, I just take the date as Dynamics passes me (System.DateTime).

Comment: Why do you care about the time? You should use the date part only.

Comment: The downstream systems that use the data care about the time being 00:00:00 as that's pretty traditional for being "date only".  Either I fix the custom service somehow or I fix the time in BizTalk.

Comment: Posted this on the Dynamics community forum as well.  Possibly looks like a bug. https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/p/179004/441069